# cannot validate certificate for 10.90.239.223 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: ssl, chef, terraform

While configuring the chef provisioner I am running into the following error after running 'terraform apply'

```
* chef_environment.terraform_01: Post https://10.90.239.223/organizations/mykitchen/environments: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.90.239.223 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

I have read that the certs may need a different 'CN' field, but I don't remember manually setting up certs as part of the [chef server install process](https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html).

I have these certs that I found after the install

```
$ls /var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca
dhparams.pem  localhost.crt  localhost.key
```

which I think are the ones being used but I'm not sure.

I also have set

```
ssl_verify_mode = ":verify_none"
```

in my chef provisioner configs, but I don't know if that's relevant or working.

Do I need to (re)generate certs, if so how would I do that for chef?  I already have certs generated for my matchbox service on the same machine using [this](https://github.com/coreos/matchbox/blob/master/scripts/tls/cert-gen) script, would I use those?

UPDATE:

I tried this

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout chef.key -out chef.pem -nodes -days 365 -config req.conf

sudo chown opscode:opscode chef.*
sudo mv chef.* /var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/.

sudo chef-server-ctl stop
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-server-ctl start
```

my req.conf

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=mystate
L=mycity
O=DevOps
OU=myname
emailAddress=myemail@mycompany.com
CN = 10.90.239.223

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP = 10.90.239.223
DNS.1 = 10.0.90.45
DNS.2 = 10.90.50.8
email = DevOps-3@10.90.239.223
URI = https://10.90.239.223/
```

but I am still getting

```
chef_environment.terraform_01: Post https://10.90.239.223/organizations/mykitchen/environments: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.90.239.223 because it doesn't contain any                                       IP SANs
```

Comment: From what you are saying the that does sound like the problem.  Maybe someone else can help me with the chef provisioning part?  I am very new to chef and terraform provisioning. I'm guessing I need to re generate the certs unless I can add the SANs to an existing cert?

Comment: SAN = Subject Alternate Name. Many web clients, e.g. Chrome, are now requiring that certificates have the host name listed in the Subject Alternate Name extension, not just in the CN field as in the past. Not sure the right way to add them as part of Chef provisioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/terraform-chef-provisioning-cannot-validate-certificate-for-10-90-239-223-beca/3170#3170. Short version don't use `openssl` to make certs anymore, it's too complex to get right.